# Why a MapRenderer derived renderer works only for a control derived from Map

Tags: xamarin.forms

I was trying to create a custom renderer for the `Map` control:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Map), typeof(MapRendererFix))]

namespace MyApp
{
   class MapRendererFix : MapRenderer
   {
   }
}
```

But the c-tor never gets called.

If however I create a derived control class `MapFix`, it works:

```
class MapFix: Map
{
}

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MapFix), typeof(MapRendererFix))]

namespace MyApp
{
   class MapRendererFix : MapRenderer
   {
   }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to me why I have to create a control derived from `Map` in order to have the custom renderer used. If I create a `MyButtonRenderer`, it is used withoug having to create a `MyButton`.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to check/test:

-Renderer should be public

-typeof(Map) reference correctly the instance of Xamarin Forms Map

Perhaps you could send more code?

Comment: No, the custom renderer class doesn't need to be public. Try it please.